# Creacion de Script para completar datos

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Mi problema consiste en generar un reporte de ubicacion por equipos teniendo la siguiente BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema con el reporte es que  la tabla equipo guarda el ID de ingreso o movimiento automaticamente pero no la ubicacion, por lo cual tendria que hacer un script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mas facil que pense fue construir una columna extra en equipo que guarde la ubicacion una vez se actualicen los datos.

Por lo cual tendria que hacer un script para llenar los datos  de esa columna teniendo encuenta que ya esta poblada la BD.

pense algo asi:

```
update equipo INNER JOIN ingreso
ON equipo.ing_ide = ingreso.ing_ide
INNER JOIN movimiento
ON equipo.mov_ide = movimiento.mov_ide
SET equipo.pun_ide = case
                     when equipo.mov_ide = '0' then ingreso.pun_ide 
                     when equipo.mov_ide != '0' then movimiento.pun_ide
                     else 'fruta'
                     end
```

Problema: que solo me actualiza por uno de los dos caminos, when `equipo.mov_ide != '0'` que error estoy cometiendo ?.

o se les ocurre una mejor idea en la generacion de este reporte?

**-------------EJEMPLO-------------------**

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ingreso` (
  `ing_ide` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ide_equipo` varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
  `pun_ide` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `hard_estado` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ing_ide`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ingreso` (`ing_ide`, `ide_equipo`,  `pun_ide`, `hard_estado`) VALUES
(1, '784476', 730012230120, '1'),
(2, '0444712', 730012230121, '1'),
(3, '2332476', 730012230122, '1'),
(4, '44476', 730012230123, '1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movimiento` (
  `mov_ide` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ide_equipo` varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
  `pun_ide` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `hard_estado` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mov_ide`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `movimiento` (`mov_ide`, `ide_equipo`,  `pun_ide`, `hard_estado`) VALUES
(1, '784476', 830012230120, '1'),
(2, '0444712', 830012230121, '2'),
(3, '2332476', 830012230122, '4');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equipo` (
  `eqi_ide` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ide_equipo` varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
  `ing_ide` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `mov_ide` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `pun_ide` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eqi_ide`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `equipo` (`eqi_ide`, `ide_equipo`, `ing_ide` , `mov_ide` ,`pun_ide`) VALUES
(1, '784476',  '1', '1' , '0' ),
(2, '0444712',  '2', '0' , '0'),
(3, '2332476',  '3', '0' , '0');

update equipo INNER JOIN ingreso
ON equipo.ing_ide = ingreso.ing_ide
INNER JOIN movimiento
ON equipo.mov_ide = movimiento.mov_ide
SET equipo.pun_ide = case
                     when equipo.mov_ide = '0' then ingreso.pun_ide 
                     else movimiento.pun_ide
                     end
```

Comment: porque tu `inner` liga por un campo `ing_ide` y `mov_ide` siendo que debieran ser `id_ig` y `id_mt` segun lo que veo en el dibujo de tus tablas? son los mismos datos? no debiera haber problema, pero es para no confundirme...

Comment: las graficas eran solo como para guiar, XD pero ahora lo edito para evitar confuciones.

Comment: `equipo.mov_ide` que dato guarda?

Comment: la llave primaria de tabla movimiento  y  es el indice que se guarda como movimiento en  la tabla equipo

Comment: yo pienso que siempre sera distinto a 0 debido a que es un tipo de dato entero, nose si autoincrementable o no. sera talves por eso que solo te condiciona en ese caso?

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo con la creacion de las tablas.@Francisco Acevedo

Comment: entonces necesitas hacer una query que actualice esta nueva columna `pun_ide` de tu tabla equipo ...  verdad? en donde pun_ide es la ubicación, entendí bien?

Comment: Exactamente eso quiero,  probe tu respuesta y sigue sin completar adecuadamente  la columna

Comment: probaste con ambas querys de la respuesta?

Comment: SI ambas, igual el campo e.mov_ide nunca va  a ser null , en caso que no tenga movimiento se completara con un '0'

Comment: listo, prueba con el query que actualice abajo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81409/discussion-between-francisco-acevedo-and-andres-felipe-diaz).

Comment: Que grande!!!  muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esta query, el error estaba en el llamado al indice:

```
                UPDATE     equipo e
                INNER JOIN ingreso  i   ON e.ide_equipo = i.ide_equipo
                INNER JOIN movimiento m ON e.ide_equipo = m.ide_equipo
                SET e.pun_ide = case 
                             when e.mov_ide = 0 then i.pun_ide 
                             when e.mov_ide != 0 then m.pun_ide
                        else 'fruta'
                        end
```